# Как в aiogram разделить диалоги по модулям и передавать управление между ними?

Tags: python, aiogram

Изучаю библиотеку aiogram, путем написания бота по поиску товаров.
По задумке, есть главное меню с тремя кнопками. кнопка дёшево: выдаёт результат поиска по возрастанию цены, лучшее предложение по цене и расстоянию до продавца и по убыванию цены.
Пользователь жмет на кнопку, меню заменяется на вопрос: введите название товара. пользователь вводит и его перекидывает в диалог, соответствующий кнопке (дешево - lowprice, дорого - highprice и т.д.) При этом надо передать объект message, в котором содержится message.text - название товара, айди пользователя и т.д.

Схему работы такова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура файлов следующая:

```
bot
|    \data
|         \requests
|             lowprice.py
|             best.py
|             highprice.py
|    keyboards.py
|main.py
|.env
```

Я пишу в main (импорты опустил)

```
bot = Bot(token=settings.API_TOKEN)
#диспетчер
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
#фабрика коллбеков
cb = CallbackData("post", "action")

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    """
    Реакция на кнопку старт. показываем заглавную клавиатуру
    """
    logger.info(f'Function{cmd_start.__name__} was called')
    message_text = f'Привет пользователь {message.from_user.id}! я бот!'
    await message.answer(message_text, reply_markup=keyboards.main_keyboard())


@dp.callback_query_handler(cb.filter(action=['low', 'best', 'high']))
async def main_menu(query: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    """
    Обрабатываем нажатие кнопок меню
    :param query:
    :param callback_data:
    :return:
    """
    logger.info(f'Function{main_menu.__name__} was called with {callback_data}')
    await query.answer()
    callback_data_action = callback_data['action']
    await bot.edit_message_text(
        f'ты нажал кнопку {callback_data_action}, вводи название товара: ',
        query.from_user.id,
        query.message.message_id
    )


try:
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
except Exception as e:
    logger.warning(f'bot was say crya')
```

и в lowprice.py уже делаю диалог. Создаю стейты, пишу функции, регистрирую хендлеры:

```
class ProductOrder(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_product_name = State()
    waiting_for_product_number = State()
    waiting_for_photo_number = State()
    waiting_for_history_saving = State()

далее функции:
def product_start:
    из найденных результатов формируеся инлайн клавиатура с похожими названиями товаров и кнопкой 
    "неправильно" Типа пользователь может выбрать нужный ввести заново.
def product_name_chosen:
    спрашваем сколько результатов выдать
def product_count_chosen:
    спрашваем сколько фотографий товара присоеденить
def photo_count_chosen:
    показываем результат и спрашиваем, сохранить ли историю
def history_chosen^
    сохраняем результат и показываем главное меню

 регистрирую хендлеры:

def register_handlers_lowprice(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(product_start, commands="lowprice", state="*")
    dp.register_message_handler(product_name_chosen, state=ProductOrder.waiting_for_city_name)
    dp.register_message_handler(product_count_chosen, state=ProductOrder.waiting_for_hotel_number)
    dp.register_message_handler(photo_count_chosen, state=ProductOrder.waiting_for_photo_number)
    dp.register_message_handler(history_chosen, state=ProductOrder.waiting_for_history_saving)

показываем главное меню
```

И уперся в вопрос, как передать управление из main в lowprice и вернуть обратно?

update: к сожалению так и не понял как последовать совету: "Передайте объект бота в функцию которая регистрирует хендлеры"

Comment: "Передавать управление" не нужно. Передайте объект бота в функцию которая регистрирует хендлеры.